# rb_load と rb_f_load の挙動の違いについて

Tags: ruby

http://bamch0h.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/06/21/000743 
上記のブロクにも書いたのですが、rb_load と rb_f_load の挙動の違いについての質問になります。

[質問内容]
rb_load() を使用して カレントディレクトリにあるファイル(例えば test.rb) をロードするようなC言語拡張を書いたときに、cannot load such file -- test.rb (LoadError) となりロードできませんでした。Kernel.#load は rb_f_load() を使用しているようで、load "test.rb" という指定でも問題なくロードできます。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/function/rb_load.html を見る限り、rb_load() は Kernel.#load の低レベルインターフェースということですが、rb_load() を使用すれば、Kernel.#load と同様のことができる。ということでもないのでしょうか？

rb_load() と rb_f_load() がある経緯について知れるならば幸いです。

Comment: ruby 1.9.1 では、 rb_f_load() の中で rb_load()が呼ばれているようですね。

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_1/load.c#L361

ruby 1.9.2 から現状に近い実装になっているようです。

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/load.c#L367

やはり、1.9.2でロードパスにカレントディレクトリが含まれなくなった ことと関連がありそうです。

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/ff1b8b75930160a12e03216defa77efcc46b0fec#diff-8962f5c4e82fc86da33bb950a9147069 このコミットで rb_f_load() の中で rb_load() を呼ばなくなっていますね。理由までは書いてないですが、コミットログには指定されたファイルがロードパスに見つからない場合は直接ロードすることを明示してありますね。

Comment: `rb_f_load()` とは異なって、`require(rb_f_require() -> rb_require_internal())` の方では `rb_file_load_ok()` を呼んでいないので `require "test.rb"` がエラーになってしまいます(`test.rb` が未ロードの場合)。`rb_f_load()` ではなく、`rb_find_file_safe()` 内でカレントディレクトリをチェックする様にしておけば仕様を統一できたのになぁ、とは思いますが…。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 2.6.3 のソースコードを調べてみました。Yamanaka さんのブログ記事に記載がある通りに `rb_load()` -> `file_to_load()` -> `load_failed()` という順序で実行が続いています。

**load.c**

```c
void
rb_load(VALUE fname, int wrap)
{
    rb_load_internal(file_to_load(fname), wrap);
}

static VALUE
file_to_load(VALUE fname)
{
    VALUE tmp = rb_find_file(FilePathValue(fname));
    if (!tmp) load_failed(fname);
    return tmp;
}

static void
load_failed(VALUE fname)
{
    rb_load_fail(fname, "cannot load such file");
}
```

問題の `rb_find_file()` ですが、`rb_find_file_safe()` へと実行が続き、load path(`$:` or `$LOAD_PATH` の内容) から指定ファイルを探索しています。

Ruby 2.6.3 の `rb_find_file_safe()` 関数内ではカレントディレクトリを調べていません。ただし、ファイル名を相対パス指定にする(`./test.rb`)か、load path に `"."` を追加すればロードされるはずです。

**file.c**

```c
static int
is_explicit_relative(const char *path)
{
  if (*path++ != '.') return 0;
  if (*path == '.') path++;
  return isdirsep(*path);
}

VALUE
rb_find_file(VALUE path)
{
    return rb_find_file_safe(path, rb_safe_level());
}

VALUE
rb_find_file_safe(VALUE path, int safe_level)
{
                   :
  if (expanded || rb_is_absolute_path(f) || is_explicit_relative(f)) {
                   :
    if (!rb_file_load_ok(f)) return 0;
    if (!expanded)
      path = copy_path_class(file_expand_path_1(path), path);
    return path;
  }
                   :
  RB_GC_GUARD(load_path) = rb_get_expanded_load_path();
  if (load_path) {
                   :
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(load_path); i++) {
      VALUE str = RARRAY_AREF(load_path, i);
      RB_GC_GUARD(str) = rb_get_path_check(str, safe_level);
      if (RSTRING_LEN(str) > 0) {
        rb_file_expand_path_internal(path, str, 0, 0, tmp);
        f = RSTRING_PTR(tmp);
        if (rb_file_load_ok(f)) goto found;
      }
    }
    rb_str_resize(tmp, 0);
    return 0;
  }
```

次に `rb_f_load()` についてですが、`rb_find_file()` で指定ファイルがロード不可と判定されるため、`rb_file_load_ok()` で再度チェックを行う事になります。こちらもブログ記事にある通りに、カレントディレクトリにそのファイルが存在して、かつ読み込み可能かどうかをチェックしています。

```c
static VALUE
rb_f_load(int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
                 :
  path = rb_find_file(fname);
  if (!path) {
    if (!rb_file_load_ok(RSTRING_PTR(fname)))
      load_failed(orig_fname);
    path = fname;
  }
                :
```

したがって、`rb_load()` では読み込みに失敗して、`rb_f_load()` では成功する事になります。

Comment: 確認ありがとうございます。コードも貼り付けていただいているので、大変わかりやすかったです。もう一点、気になっている部分としては、リファレンスマニュアルの rb_load() の章には「組込み関数 Kernel.#load の低レベルインタフェースです。」との記載があるので、私としては、rb_load() を使用すれば Kernel.#load と同様のことができるのではないか？と思っていたんですが、実際はできず、rb_f_load() を使わなければならないのはなぜだろう？という部分です。「昔はrb_load()を使っていたが、今はrb_f_load()に置き換えられて、rb_load()は古い実装だ。互換性のために残してある」等の理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: https://jp.quora.com/Ruby%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C-1-9-2%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92/answers/151435181?__filter__&__nsrc__=2&__snid3__=4739365422

https://jp.quora.com/load-c-%E3%81%AB-rb_load-%E3%81%A8-rb_f_load-%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Quoraで質問してみましたが、うまく回答を引き出せなかったので、今回の件はこれで終わりにしようと思います。